# Reproductibility of the effects described in US patent 8,419,919

Tags: atomic-physics, cold-fusion

[US patent 8,419,919](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/8419919), by P. Boss, F. Gordon, S. Szpak, and L. Forsley, describes what (I summarize) would be a method to perform particle generation leading to atomic transmutation, by palladium electrolysis in heavy water with electrolytic current increasing over time, combined with an (e.g.) magnetic field applied to the setup.

The text of the patent includes elements of description of laboratory experiments, and report in particular that a chemical [CR-39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR-39) particle detector records tracks (presumably due to an alpha source) *selectively* when the electrolysis is performed in the presence of the magnetic field. This would be extremely remarkable, if not an artifact.

Are these experiments and effects described in something closer to an academic paper? Is there some honest report of attempt by skilled experimentalists to recreate these experiments and effects in well equipped laboratories?

Comment: What do you mean by "publicly"? In front of an audience? That's not how science works. Just because something is demonstrated in front of the public does not make it true. The whole art of magical illusion is based on almost scientific methods that set up "demonstrations" of seemingly impossible effects. A patent, by the way, is a legal and not a scientific document. The claims in it are not validated by a peer review process. Neither is a patent, all by itself, a watertight legal right to exploit an invention. Anybody can challenge it in court, though in this case probably nobody will.

Comment: @CuriousOne: By publicly I meant: that can been reported; by opposition to classified. I'll fix the question.

Comment: The only reasonable question to science that I can see is this: Have there been honest attempts by skilled experimentalists to recreate this in well equipped laboratories which have resulted in scientific publications? The answer to that is, yes, there have been. One of them was done by a physicist who I know personally and it was done meticulously. The results of that experiment were as negative as one can imagine. You can run a literature search on cold fusion and you will find plenty of articles. Cold fusion, by the way, is real, it just doesn't work the way this patent suggests.

Comment: @CuriousOne: "Cold fusion, by the way, is real..." Could you put up a source on that?

Comment: Muon catalysed fusion

Comment: @DanielSank: Dirk Bruere got it. Muon catalyzed fusion is quite "cool" and it almost works... just not quite, at least not the last time I heard about it.

Comment: Awesome.  If it works then, I look forward to cheap energy in the next five years.  

For some reason, these people never just have the thing go and power a car, or a light bulb.  I just can't understand why...

Comment: Cold fusion not going to happen, due to invalid claims of overcoming high nucleosynthesis energy threshold with "magic devices".  If one needs to fuse a pair of Hydrogen nuclei, then they need to overcome Coulomb energy barrier of about $1~\text{MeV}$, for that they need to speed-up Hydrogen atoms to $\approx 5\%~\text{of}~c$ and squash them together head-to-head. So, unless this is a true **particle accelerator**, it never happen in typical electrolysis reaction with or without magnetic fields.

Answer (score 4):

The whole field of Cold Fusion is now viewed by many scientists as pathological science. If such a thing does exist and produces non-trivial amounts of heat then the only way it is going to be validated is if/when units are commercially available for power generation. By this, I do not mean Rossi style demonstrations. I mean units that engineers can take away, reverse engineer and analyse in their own time in their own labs.

Comment: I concur on current claims of cold fusion as a practical way to produce non-trivial amounts of energy. However the exposition in the patent I refer to does not describe any production of energy (much to the contrary: a lot is absorbed).